# can we initialize a typedef word with zero?

Tags: c, initialization, typedef

I tried to initialize a **typedef word** with 0, it still works. but is that the right way to do it?

```
typedef word      ind_t;
ind_t            ind = 0;
```

Comment: Remember that a typedef is just an alias for the original type. So in your case `ind_t` is an alias for `word`. So the answer to your question is: If a `word` variable can be initialized with `0`, then an `ind_t` variable also can be.

Comment: For future questions, please include a proper [mre] to show us. What is, for example, the non-standard type `word`? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the right way to do it.

In your example `ind_t` is the type and `ind` is the variable/object. We cannot "initialize types", because that doesn't make sense. It is however perfectly fine and correct to initialize a variable with an initializer that is valid for the variable's declared type.

There's no difference between your code and something like `int i=0;`. Naturally we can't write `int=0;` because that's nonsense. Types obtained through `typedef` are no different.

Comment: well although i agree if he replaces "word" with void it will fail as it's incomplete

Comment: @Imeguras I don't see how that's meaningful or relevant.

Comment: yeah, my doubt was if we can initialize a type word with 0.

Comment: @Lundin im just saying that as stated by you and Some programmer dude since typedef in this case acts as an alias althought it will work with most types void obviously fails

Comment: @Imeguras And what would be the sane reason to ever typedef void?

Comment: @Imeguras OP said it works, so `word` must be some type where `0` is a valid initializer for objects of that type.

Comment: @Lundin well void itself you wouldn't(at least from what i recall) but if it was a pointer to void i've seen various alias being used that way, for defining custom default behavior on library implementations
Ian Abbott yep i guess you're right